# Spring webclient testing with okhttp3 Mockwebserver

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp, spring-webclient

I am unable to moock webclient

**WebClientConfig.java**

```
public @Bean("oauthWebClient") WebClient oauthWebClient() {

    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                    HttpClient.create().option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000)
                            .doOnConnected(connection -> connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10))
                                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(10)))))
            .filter(logOAuthResponse()).baseUrl(oauthTokenUrl)

            .defaultHeaders(headers -> {

                headers.setBasicAuth(secretHeaderValue);
                headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);

            })

            .defaultUriVariables(oauthUriVariables)

            .build();
}
```

**serviceUti.java**
package com.test.stats.volts.busops.utils;

```
        import java.util.Map;

        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
        import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
        import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
        import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
        import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover;
        import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
        import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
        import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException;
        import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException;

        import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
        import com.test.stats.volts.busops.exception.VoltsDataAccessException;
        import com.test.stats.volts.busops.exception.MtnDataAccessNotRespondingException;
        import com.test.stats.volts.busops.exception.VoltsDataAcessException;
        import com.test.stats.volts.busops.exception.UnableToGetOAuthTokenException;


        @Component("voltsDataAccessServiceUtil")
        public class ServiceUtil {

            private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceUtil.class);

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("voltsDataAccessWebClient")
            WebClient voltsDataAccessClient;

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("oauthWebClient")
            WebClient oauthClient;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.end.point.save-meeting}")
            private String saveMeetingEndPoint;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.oauth.header-key.name}")
            private String oauthHeaderKeyName;

            @Value("${volts.dataccess.oauth.response.token.key-name}")
            private String oauthResponseTokenKeyName;

            @Value("#{${volts.dataaccess.api.endpoints.default.uri-variables}}")
            private Map<String, String> voltsDataAccessUriVariables;

            @Autowired
            ObjectMapper mapper;

            @Value("#{${volts.dataaccess.oauth.uri-variables}}")
            private Map<String, String> oauthUriVariables;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.oauth.scope}")
            private String oauthScope;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.oauth.grant_type}")
            private String grantType;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.oauth.secret.header-name}")
            private String secretHeaderName;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.oauth.secret.header-value}")
            private String secretHeaderValue;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.end.point.fetch-meeting}")
            private String fetchMeetingEndPoint;

            @Value("${volts.dataaccess.query.param.api-key-value}")
            private String apiKey;

            @Retryable(maxAttempts = 2)
            public String postOAuthToken() throws VoltsDataAccessException {

                try {

                    String respEntity = oauthClient.post()

                            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("scope", oauthScope).queryParam("grant_type", grantType)
                                    .build())
                            .headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth(secretHeaderValue))

                            .retrieve()

                            .bodyToMono(String.class)

                            .block();

                    if (respEntity == null)
                        throw new UnableToGetOAuthTokenException(
                                "Exception while fetching OAUthToken as response from OAUth service is null resposne body");

                    try {
                        return mapper.readValue(respEntity, ObjectNode.class).get(oauthResponseTokenKeyName).asText();
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

                        logger.error("Exception while pasring token from Oauth ", e);
                        throw new UnableToGetOAuthTokenException(
                                "Exception while fetching OAUthToken as response from OAUth service is null resposne body");

                    }
                } catch (WebClientRequestException e) {
                    logger.error("Request Exception to OAUth: message {}", e.getMessage(), e);
                    logger.error("", e);
                    throw new VoltsDataAccessException(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT.value());
                }

                catch (WebClientResponseException e) {

                    
                    throw new VoltsDataAccessException(e.getMessage(), e.getRawStatusCode());
                }
            }

            @Retryable(value = VoltsDataAcessException.class)
            public ResponseEntity<VoltsResp> postSaveMeetingDetails(SaveVoltsReq voltsReq)
                    throws VoltsDataAcessException {

                try {

                    ResponseEntity<VoltsResp> resp = voltsDataAccessClient.post()
                            .uri(saveMeetingEndPoint, uri -> uri.queryParam("apikey", apiKey).build())
                            .headers(headers -> headers.setBearerAuth(postOAuthToken()))

                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(voltsReq).retrieve()

                            .toEntity(VoltsResp.class).block();

                    return resp;
                } catch (WebClientRequestException e) {
                    throw new VoltsDataAcessException(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT.value());
                } catch (WebClientResponseException e) {
                    throw new VoltsDataAcessException(e.getMessage(), e.getRawStatusCode());
                }

            }


        }
```

My test classs

**WebClienrTests.java**

```
            import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

        import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
        import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
        import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
        import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
        import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

        import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
        import com.test.stats.volts.busops.config.WebClientConfig;
        import com.test.stats.volts.busops.utils.ServiceUtil;

        import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
        import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;

        @SpringBootTest(classes = { ServiceUtil.class, WebClientConfig.class,
                ObjectMapper.class })
        @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        class ServiceUtilTests {

            public static MockWebServer mockServer = new MockWebServer();

            @MockBean
            WebClientConfig webClientCondfig;

            @Autowired
            ServiceUtil serviceUtil;

            @MockBean(name = "oauthWebClient")
            WebClient oauthClient;

            @MockBean(name = "voltsDataAccessWebClient")
            WebClient voltsDataAccessWebClient;

            @BeforeEach
            void startMockServer() throws Exception {

                mockServer.start(9090);

                oauthClient = WebClient.create(mockServer.url("/").url().toString());
            }

            @AfterEach
            void stopMockServer() throws Exception {
                mockServer.shutdown();
            }

            @Test
            void testPostOAuth() throws Exception {
                mockServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody("OAuthToken"));
                String expected = serviceUtil.postOAuthToken();
                assertThat(expected).isNotNull().isEqualTo("OAuthToken");
            }

        }
```

When I run above test I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
```

At `postAuthToken()` while setting headers `.headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth(secretHeaderValue))`

Please help on how to mock whole thing

Comment: What's your intent for this test? Write an integration test for your whole application or test your ServiceUtil in isolation? Please also add the whole import section for your test. It seems you're mixing JUnit 4 and 5. This might a good read on [getting started with unit & integration testing for Spring Boot applications](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-unit-and-integration-testing-overview/).

Comment: @rieckpil I have edited my question please check now, I am actually trying to test `postoauthToken()` method in `ServiceUtil.java`  its throwing me `NulPOinterException` at setting up headers

Comment: then please also add the whole source code for the `ServiceUtil` class here to understand its dependencies. Please also make sure your code is properly formatted.

Comment: Added Please check.

Comment: @rieckpil do you need more info ?